# Data from the backend is not appearing when you assign it into new object on the front end

Tags: reactjs

Question, I have this list of task coming from my backend, I dunno why my data is not appearing when I assign this to new object. I'm planning to create a drag and drop task component.

**Datas**
[image]

```
const BoardView = ({ datas, showTask, taskInfo }) => {
const [filteredList, setFilteredList] = useState(datas);

const listColumns = {
    [uuidv4()]: {
      name: 'Proposed',
      items: filteredList,
    },
    [uuidv4()]: {
      name: 'In Progress',
      items: [],
    },
    [uuidv4()]: {
      name: 'Review',
      items: [],
    },
    [uuidv4()]: {
      name: 'Done',
      items: [],
    },
  };

console.log(datas) => data is appearing
return (
    <>
      <div className='w-full p-8 grid grid-flow-col grid-cols-4 gap-8'>
        <DragDropContext
          onDragEnd={(result) => onDragEnd(result, columns, setColumns)}
        >
          {Object.entries(columns).map(([columnId, column], index) => {
            return (
              <div
                style={{
                  display: 'flex',
                  flexDirection: 'column',
                  alignItems: 'center',
                }}
                key={columnId}
              >
                {console.log(column.item)} => there's no data
              </div>
            );
          })}
        </DragDropContext>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: Data should be assigned to a state variable , if you need to reflect that on your template

Comment: I also assign first the datas to a state variable but the output is the same.

Comment: @rjc30 this is because when the state(`datas`) is assigned to `filteredList`, the data has not been fetched yet. Try doing the data fetching internally in the `BoardView` component

Comment: @rjc30 Where are you settings value for `columns`

Comment: I'm stupid I forgot to set the variable using useEffect. Thanks for the help guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your API endpoint is being hit when you are loading the component. Currently your component is loaded whilst the data is not yet fetched. So we'll fetch the data and then render the component

For this, wrap the logic for fetching the data in a `useEffect` hook - where you do 2 things -

1. Fetch the data
2. Populate the state with fetched data

Something like :

```
const BoardView = ({ datas, showTask, taskInfo }) => {
    const [filteredList, setFilteredList] = useState(datas);
    
    const listColumns = {
        [uuidv4()]: {
          name: 'Proposed',
          items: filteredList,
        },
        [uuidv4()]: {
          name: 'In Progress',
          items: [],
        },
        [uuidv4()]: {
          name: 'Review',
          items: [],
        },
        [uuidv4()]: {
          name: 'Done',
          items: [],
        },
    };
    
    useEffect(async () => {
        // 1. => Fetching the data using "fetchAPI" or "axios". I have chosen axios as it is easier to work with
        const results = await axios.get('API__ENDPOINT')
        
        // 2. => Populate the state of this current component with fetched data 
        setFilteredList(results)
    },[results])
    
    console.log(datas) => data is appearing
    return (
        <>
          <div className='w-full p-8 grid grid-flow-col grid-cols-4 gap-8'>
            <DragDropContext
              onDragEnd={(result) => onDragEnd(result, columns, setColumns)}
            >
              {Object.entries(columns).map(([columnId, column], index) => {
                return (
                  <div
                    style={{
                      display: 'flex',
                      flexDirection: 'column',
                      alignItems: 'center',
                    }}
                    key={columnId}
                  >
                    {console.log(column.item)} => there's no data
                  </div>
                );
              })}
            </DragDropContext>
          </div>
        </>
      );
    };
```